# Why I get error in Azure Function when use async/Task, but when use these in Console App, there is no error?

Tags: c#, async-await, task, azure-functions

This is how I use async/Task in Console App:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace CaseDurableFunctionConsole
{

    class Program
    {
        static async Task<List<string>> RunOrchestrator()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Hello World!");
            Console.ReadLine();
            var outputs = new List<string>();
            return outputs;
        }

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            RunOrchestrator();
        }
    }
}
```

This works well and this is the output:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lFk5m.png)

(Even without using await, it shows the right result.)

But when I use async/Task in Azure Functions, like this:

```
[FunctionName("Function1")]
public static async Task<List<string>> RunOrchestrator(
    [OrchestrationClient] DurableOrchestrationClient orchestrationClient)
{
    var outputs = new List<string>();
    await Task.Delay(1);
    return outputs;
}
```

Then it comes up with an error after started.

> [2019/11/25 5:50:50] Error indexing method 'Function1' [2019/11/25
> 5:50:50] Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host: Error indexing method
> 'Function1'. Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host: Functions must return Task
> or void, have a binding attribute for the return value, or be
> triggered by a binding that natively supports return values.
>
> [2019/11/25 5:50:56] The 'Function1' function is in error:
> Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host: Error indexing method 'Function1'.
> Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host: Functions must return Task or void, have
> a binding attribute for the return value, or be triggered by a binding
> that natively supports return values.

How can I fix this by modify my Function Code?

Answer (score 1):

This has nothing to do with `async-await`.

The log message states that, for that binding, the method should return `Task` or `void` and your method returns `Task<List<string>>`.

Your function method does not equate to the `RunOrchestrator` method in your console application. It equates to the `Main` method.

Comment: Thank you for reply. I feel that you should be right, but how can I return Task? I am a little dizzy about that.

Comment: Have you tried just making the method signature `public static async Task RunOrchestrator([OrchestrationClient] DurableOrchestrationClient orchestrationClient)`?

Answer (score 0):

Checked the documentation, here is the [reason](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/durable/durable-functions-orchestrations#durable-timers):

> Orchestrations can schedule *durable timers* to implement delays or to set up timeout handling on async actions. Use durable timers in orchestrator functions instead of `Thread.Sleep` and `Task.Delay` (C#) or `setTimeout()` and `setInterval()` (JavaScript).
>
> For more information and for examples, see the [Durable timers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/durable/durable-functions-timers) article.

Comment: Hi, Jack. Do you have any suggestions of how to modify my code? Actually, I don't know how to modify the code to avoid this problem.

Comment: Check the sample: [Orchestrator.cs](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/durablefunctions-apiscraping-dotnet/blob/master/FanOutFanInCrawler/Orchestrator.cs)

Answer (score 0):

Due to replay constraints of orchestrators, you mustn't await anything other than the orchestration context, or use sleep methods.

To wait, in a durable "replay" safe way, try:

```
await orchestrator.CreateTimer(orchestrator.CurrentUtcDateTime.AddMinutes(15), CancellationToken.None);
```

Also, you don't appear to have implemented an orchestration trigger function correctly.  You need a trigger parameter such as:

```
[OrchestrationTrigger] IDurableOrchestrationContext orchestrator
```